# Submit screenshots to Office Store

Tags: office-js, office-store

I am submitting an Office Add-in to the Office Store.

For the screenshots, I have made `png` of `1366px x 768px`, but after `Save as draft`, I always see this, rather than a thumbnail:

[image]

What does it mean? Can I still submit this screenshot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an office-store support question, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected display for the 'Optional' screenshots. A thumbnail is generated for the mandatory screenshot only. Once you upload the screenshots, and submit the listing to validation, the screenshots will display as expected once approved to the Office Store.